# Running a stored procedure from crontab

Tags: mysql, linux, cron

I have the layout:

```
Mysql DB
DB name: db_name
DB User name: user_name
Password: 12345
Stored procedure: my_stored_procedure
```

How can I execute "my_stored_procedure" daily from a crontab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to run something like this

```
mysql -h 'your ipadress' -u user_name –p'12345' mydatabase -e 'CALL my_stored_procedure()'
```

Just a guess i dont know if it will work.

Answer (score 3):

I think better to use  Events from mysql.

For more information please visit [Using the Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html)

Or use solution suggested by [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377059/running-a-stored-procedure-from-crontab/5377115#5377115). 
Personally  I like to execut mysql using **-ss** and socket file:

```
mysql -S/path_to_sock_file/mysql.sock -u user_name –p'12345' mydatabase -ss  -e 'CALL my_stored_procedure()'
```

**-ss**  returns results as a plain text.

Cheers Arman.