# Call stored procedure from crontab for every 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cron

How to call a stored procedure from crontab for every 10 minutes? Syntax and Example will be more useful.

I referred this example [Running a stored procedure from crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377059/running-a-stored-procedure-from-crontab) but for where to specify every 10 minutes.

Comment: `*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/mysql -h 'your ipadress' -u user_name –p'12345' mydatabase -e 'CALL my_stored_procedure()'`

Comment: Here ipadress is my system 'localhost:8080' or phpmyadmin 'localhost:3306'

Comment: Mysql default port is 3306, when you use default port you don't need to add it, just use "localhost".